# HTTP to HTTPS redirection tomcat base url not redirected

Tags: tomcat, ssl, redirect

web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Secured Core Context</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
   </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

server.xml

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"      connectionTimeout="20000" debug="0" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" keystoreFile="./conf/Community.keystore" keystorePass="****" maxSpareThreads="75" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" name="SSL" port="9255" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" sslProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"/>

<Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" debug="3" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxSpareThreads="75" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" name="WebServer" port="8090" redirectPort="9255"/>
```

Im able to run the app in http as well as https. While accessing http://localhost:8090 it does not redirect to https. But if I access http://localhost:8090/html/login.html it redirects to https. What am I missing here?